# Laying out buttons on rows and columns that stretch up to a maximum width

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to layout 4 rows which contain 2 buttons each side by side. The tricky part (at least for me) is that the buttons need to be of the same width and height with a minimum and maximum width and height and centered in it's container. I can live with a code solution for the same width and height.

I've tried the following layout, but the button doesn't seem to respect the max width, it always stretches with the column past it's maximum allowed width.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:minWidth="64"
        android:minHeight="64"
        android:maxWidth="128"
        android:maxHeight="128" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:minWidth="64"
        android:minHeight="64"
        android:maxWidth="128"
        android:maxHeight="128" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
</TableRow>
```

Any help is appreciated...

Update:
I would like the following:

```
-----------------------
|   btn1   |   btn2   |
|   btn3   |   btn4   |
|   btn5   |   btn6   |
|   btn7   |   btn8   |
-----------------------
```

The idea is for the layout to expand 100% of the width and thus so do the columns and buttons. But the buttons should only expand up to a maximum width and center themselves to the column.

Comment: Did you try defining weights in the TableRows and its elements?

Comment: It will be greatly appreciated if you show an example of what you want

Comment: Yes, the description is a bit vague. Assuring buttons have the same width is fine (`match_parent` each button and assign equal weights to each button, equal to the sum defined in the table row weight). But I'm wondering about assuring they are the same height... is cropping acceptable? Do you know in advance if you'll have cropped labels (in this case, a simple definition will probably work). If not, then working in run time may be solution. Too many questions here.

Comment: Just updated the question to show what I mean

Comment: @JonasStawski, Have you seen my updated image..? Just tell me what is the problem in it. Maybe I can solve this problem for you...

Comment: @HishamMuneer I commented on it.

Answer (score 0):

You must try margins, although I didn't get your question completely. Sorry :) but I tried...

[image]

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="#fff000"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >

    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: The idea is for the table to expand 100%, padding won't work, because the screen size is not the same on all devices

Comment: You have a fixed margin, which won't work on different screen resolutions.

Comment: @JonasStawski, Only the margin is problem, else you want the exact same result?? Reply

Comment: Yes, I'm testing calculating the margin programmatically. Maybe that would do. But this is such a simple task that can be easily accomplish in other technologies like HTML and XAML. It shouldn't be that complicated.